# Confluent kafka python API - how to get number of partitions in a topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I would like to get the number of partitions within a topic but the API is difficult to understand at best.

I found the following, but, the topic information doesn't contain the numbers of partitions.

```
import confluent_kafka
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, ConfigResource

kafkaServers =  ["***","****"]

bootstrapServers = ",".join(kafkaServers)
adminClient = AdminClient({
    'bootstrap.servers': bootstrapServers
})

result = adminClient.describe_configs([ConfigResource(confluent_kafka.admin.RESOURCE_TOPIC, "model-detections-dev")])

config = list(result.values())[0].result()
```

[image]

how can I get the number of partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partitions are not a "topic config" to be gotten from the AdminClient.

You can use a [Consumer instance](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#pythonclient-consumer) to get them

`consumer.list_topics()` returns `ClusterMetadata`, which holds a map of topics to [`TopicMetadata`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.TopicMetadata), which has a  `partitions` attribute. Take its length to find number of partitions.

Comment: What if I dont have any consumers yet and I just want to investigate the topic.

Comment: I'd start with using `kcat` or `kafka-topics.sh` rather than Python. Otherwise, you can assign or subscribe a consumer instance without polling any data from the topic